# how to generate share secret using bouncy castle

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have 2 byte arrays of ECDSA private and public key how can i generate share secret. I have found following java code. I have tried following

```
ECPublicKeyParameters otherPartyPublicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(publicKeyBytes);
ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyBytes);
IBasicAgreement aKeyAgree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDH");
        aKeyAgree.Init(privateKey);
BigInteger sharedSecret = aKeyAgree.CalculateAgreement(otherPartyPublicKey);
```

but i'm getting error "DEF length 118 object truncated by 55"

Comment: Please clarify what format 'publicKeyBytes' and 'privateKeyBytes' are provided in. Also, why not share with us the details (i.e. the stack trace) of the exception?

Comment: thx for your reply. i have changed my code. now my problem is java shared secret and c# shared secret are not same for same key pair. I used P-256 in c# and secp256r1 in java

Comment: You have changed your code... but you have not shared it with us, nor provided the extra information I requested above.

Comment: I have solved my problem. Im updating the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i solved my problem. Main problem was curve spec

```
        X9ECParameters ecP = NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
        ECDomainParameters eCDomainParameters = new ECDomainParameters(ecP.Curve, ecP.G, ecP.N);
        ECCurve curve = eCDomainParameters.Curve;
        ECPoint q = curve.DecodePoint(publicKeyBytes);
        ECPublicKeyParameters oEcPublicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(q, eCDomainParameters);
        Console.WriteLine(new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes));
        ECPrivateKeyParameters privateKey = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes), eCDomainParameters);
        IBasicAgreement aKeyAgree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDH");
        aKeyAgree.Init(privateKey);
        BigInteger sharedSecret = aKeyAgree.CalculateAgreement(oEcPublicKeyParameters);
```